# How to Resolve DNN Error Occurred When Request AddModule

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've developed a custom DNN module using the DNN web forms template found at christoc.com.  The solution builds without error and the resulting install package installs without issue in my DNN 9.2 instance.

When I attempt to add the custom module to a page, I receive the above error.  Chrome developer tools shows further information as follows:

```
POST http://localhost:81/API/internalservices/controlbar/AddModule 500 
(Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.js?cdv=150:9566
ajax @ jquery.js?cdv=150:9173
jQuery.ajax @ jquery-migrate.js?cdv=150:191
request @ ModuleService.js?cdv=150:30
addModule @ ModuleDialog.js?cdv=150:214
_doAddModule @ ModuleDialog.js?cdv=150:794
proxy @ jquery.js?cdv=150:496
dispatch @ jquery.js?cdv=150:5206
elemData.handle @ jquery.js?cdv=150:5014
```

The standard DNN modules like HTML install onto the same page without issue.  I just applied the 9.2 most recent upgrade package to the instance which is running the generic DNN skin.

It seems that there's an issue with JQuery but I'm unsure where the issue resides and how to remedy it.  Any help and guidance would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
I wanted to share a segment of the DNN Manifest file as this may be the root cause, but am unsure.  Sample is as follows:

```
<moduleControl>
                <controlKey>Product AccountLink</controlKey>
                <controlSrc>DesktopModules/MyModuleName/P_View_AccountLink.ascx</controlSrc>
                <supportsPartialRendering>False</supportsPartialRendering>
                <controlTitle>AccountLink Content</controlTitle>
                <controlType>View</controlType>
                <iconFile />
                <helpUrl />
                <viewOrder>0</viewOrder>
                <supportsPopUps>True</supportsPopUps>
</moduleControl>
```

UPDATE 2:  I've learned that the View that's intended to be the first to be seen when the module is viewed on a page must have controlKey set to nothing in the DNN Manifest.  After doing this, removing the module, reinstalling it, and attempting to place on the page, the following error was thrown:

```
AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:5386839d-258e-4214-ae27-fb0bbae8837a
AssemblyVersion:
PortalId:-1
UserId:-1
TabId:-1
RawUrl:
Referrer:
UserAgent:

ExceptionHash:rtw8cf/KL7W//vxFceePqix1IGE=
Message:Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

StackTrace:
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at 
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) at 
DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Pane.IsVesionableModule(ModuleInfo moduleInfo) at 
DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Pane.InjectModule(ModuleInfo module) at 
DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.InjectModule(Pane pane, ModuleInfo module)

InnerMessage:
InnerStackTrace:
Source:mscorlib
FileName:
FileLineNumber:0
FileColumnNumber:0
Method:
```

So at this point, the module still does not add properly to the page.  I noted the following entry in the SQL Server DNN EventLog table:

```
<LogProperties>
   <LogProperty>
     <PropertyName>AbsoluteURL</PropertyName>
     <PropertyValue>/Default.aspx</PropertyValue>
   </LogProperty>
   <LogProperty>
     <PropertyName>DefaultDataProvider</PropertyName>
     <PropertyValue>DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, 
     DotNetNuke</PropertyValue>
   </LogProperty>
   <LogProperty>
     <PropertyName>ExceptionGUID</PropertyName>
     <PropertyValue>5386839d-258e-4214-ae27-fb0bbae8837a</PropertyValue>
  </LogProperty>
</LogProperties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I't been a while, but I believe I got a similar error with one of my modules once. 
It could be added to a page on older installations without problems, and installing in DNN 9 was also fine. But adding it to a page in DNN 9 would not work.
The problem was a mismatch between what was listed in the `.DNN` file and the actual contents of the install package.

I think it was a `moduleControls` node in `moduleDefinitions` that did not exist anymore, or it was the other way around.

Anyway match all items in the DNN file with actual files and remove/add defenitions and reinstall the package.

Comment: I've added a segment of my DNN Manifest file for your review.  The documentation does not indicate any deprecated nodes as far as I could determine.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Yes.  It turned out that the View that's to be the startup needed an empty controlKey entry in the DNN Manifest.  Thanks much for your help!!